# Calculate difference between 2

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I have a DE with the number of customers, like this:

| Entry_Date | Customer_Total | New_Customers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 05/26/2021 | 5 |  |
| 05/27/2021 | 10 | 5 |
| 05/28/2021 | 21 | 11 |

I need to calculate the value for new customers daily, which would be the difference of Customer_Total for current day vs previous day. So, for 5/27/2021 it would be 10-5, for 5/28 21-10.

Getting an error

> Errors: Old style JOIN (ANSI JOINs) syntax is not allowed.

when using below query:

```sql
SELECT
(
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM x WHERE datediff(day, Entry_Date, getdate()) = 0)) - (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM x WHERE datediff(day, Entry_Date, getdate()) = 1))
) as counter
```

What is the best way query this in marketing cloud?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you already have a data extension totalling the entries by date, you can use an Outer Apply to get the previous day's count for the calculation:

```sql
select
  convert(date, es.entry_date) entry_date
, es.customer_total 
, (es.customer_total - p.customer_total) new_customers
from Entry_Summary es
outer apply (
  select
  es0.customer_total
  from Entry_Summary es0
  where es0.entryDate >= convert(date, es.entry_date-1)
  and es0.entryDate < convert(date, es.entry_date)
) p
```

The convert() to a `date` datatype is for stripping the time from the date.